# untrusted HTML in d3.js v4 and AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unicode, d3.js

I am having issue with special character not being displayed properly, I am generating a d3.js tree layout diagram via an angular JS directive, text is being added into the diagram by the directive but any special character is not displayed properly, instead of apostrophe I get &#39; and &amp; instead of & etc... I have tried the use of a filter `$filter('html')(d.name)` with no luck

```
    app.filter('html',function($sce){
    return function(input){
        var value = input.toString();
        console.log(input);
        var output = $sce.trustAsHtml(value);
        console.log(output);
        return output;
    }
});
```

I also tried the following:

```
 nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("dy", 3)
      .attr("x", 1e-6)

      .attr("compile-template","")
      .attr("ng-bind-html", function(d) {
        var output = $sce.trustAsHtml(d.name);  
        return output;
      })
```

OR

```
    nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("dy", 3)
      .attr("x", 1e-6)
     .text(function(d) {
        var output = $sce.trustAsHtml(d.name);  
        return output;
      })
```

Both without luck, is there any other way to get special characters to display through my directive?

Comment: Are you appending this text to an SVG?

Comment: yes sir! @GerardoFurtado I think I know where you are going there, the svg can't interpret the html? I used the replace function in the string to replace the &amp#39; and &amp; and that works but is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: I was right now writing an answer... you cant use HTML entities in SVG. Can you change them to unicode? Or are you getting the text as a string with the HTML entities in it?

Comment: Is there a pre-established javascript function for that? Go ahead and write your answer, I def had not thought about the fact it was an SVG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that, right now, you are trying to use an [HTML entity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) in the SVG text element, and this won't work.

The first solution is just changing the HTML entity for the proper [Unicode](http://unicode-table.com/en/). For instance, to show an ampersand, instead of:

```
.text("&amp;")
```

or

```
.text("&#38;")
```

You should do:

```
.text("\u0026")
```

Check the snippet:

```js
var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 400)
    .attr("height", 200);
 
svg.append("text")
    .attr("x", 10)
    .attr("y", 20)
    .text("This is an ampersand with HTML entity:  &amp; (not good)");

svg.append("text")
    .attr("x", 10)
    .attr("y", 50)
    .text("This is an ampersand with Unicode: \u0026 (perfect)");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

The second solution involves using the HTML entities without changing them. If changing all your HTML entities to Unicode is not an option to you, you can append an [foreign object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject), which accepts HTML entities.