# Unicode label is not displayed as a Fontawesome icon

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js, angular-nvd3, angularjs-nvd3-directives

I am creating a chart using angular-nvd3
I got a problem when I try to display an icon where it's a label.

```
$scope.data = [
            {
                "key": "Series2",
                "values": [
                    {
                        "label" : '&#xf015;',
                        "value" : 0.56
                    } ,
                    {
                        "label" : "&#xf015;" ,
                        "value" : 0.20
                    } ,
                    {
                        "label" : "&#xf015;" ,
                        "value" : 0.10
                    } 
                ]
            }
        ]
```

But when it displayed on the chart it got an unicode label:

```
<text dy=".32em" x="-5" y="0" style="text-anchor: end;">&amp;#xf015;</text>
```

`&amp;#xf015;` this is what it's actually show on HTML but it should display `&#xf015;`

Anyone have experience with this ? Or any ideas for me ? Thank you
Here is plnkr URL: http://plnkr.co/edit/PygsTn?p=preview

Comment: I just answered this same question (if I understand it correctly): you're using an HTML entity, which won't work in an SVG. Use Unicode instead, have a look at answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38956615/untrusted-html-in-d3-js-v4-and-angularjs/38958019#38958019

Comment: I found it also. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace this:  `&#xf015;` by `\uf015`

use `\u` instead of `\\`

It's from @Gerardo Furtado answer: [untrusted HTML in d3.js v4 and AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38956615/untrusted-html-in-d3-js-v4-and-angularjs/38958019#38958019)